# Sampling Size for a large Dataset

Tags: distributions, sample-size, sample, computational-statistics

I am having a dataset of size upwards of 200 million rows. I have no knowledge of the distribution of this dataset. Would like to perform some analysis on this - like look at the `summary` metrics for a certain feature. Look at the distributions of a feature in relation to other feature(s).

I can't download all this data. Here are my specific questions -

1. What kind of Sampling size & Sampling Strategies should I be trying.
2. Is Random sampling good enough? What should be the size of the sample? Would 1 million random samples be a good enough representation of the entire 200 million?
3. How can I arrive at the optimal SampleSize without knowing inherent data distribution & minimizing sampling bias?

Comment: Just to clarify: are rows your samples (not features)?

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius - you are correct. Each rows have n features.

Comment: You also say you cannot download all this data. Are there restrictions on how much you can download or is it simply that the dataset is too big. For example: would you be able to download 1 million rows 200 times?

Comment: nope its its TeraBytes. Cant download period. Sampling is the way to go. How to find the representative sample set?